# Cordova Project in Visual studio 2015 RC Media not defined even when plugin included

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, plugins, media

I have a Visual studio 2015 Cordova Project.
When I try to use the "Media" plugin I got an error of "Media is not defined".

In Visual Studio I have included the plugin , but it doesn't work.

I had the project before created in Eclipse and it worked properly.

Do you have any idea what to do next?

This is a part of config.xml located in the root of the project

```
  <vs:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation" version="0.3.11" />
  <vs:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" version="1.3.3" />
  <vs:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media" version="0.2.16" />
  <vs:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" version="0.3.0" />
  <vs:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-motion" version="0.2.11" />
  <vs:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" version="0.6.0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue on cordova in visual studio 2015.

Tried to install "cordova-plugin-media-playback" and solved the issue immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the plugin directly via Git.

I.e:,

- Open build.xml
- Click "Plugins" on the left
- Click the "Custom" tab and check "git"
- Then use the repo: https://github.com/whitecolor/cordova-plugin-media-playback.git

This worked for me. I must have spent 2 hours debugging this silly issue.